# wcf Pass Parameter But error 400

Tags: c#, json, web-services, wcf, post

I'm call service 
http://xxxx:8102/GetDataOragn.svc/Test
but get 400 bad request

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Test", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = 
WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[OperationContract]
Result Test(string s);

[OperationBehavior]
    public Result Test(string s)
    {
        return new Result() { Code = 0, Description = s, State =true };
    }
```

---

input:
i'm using postman and

```
Content-Type:application/json
Body:raw
{
 "s":"THIS IS A TEXT MESSAGE"
}
```

Help

Answer (score 0):

your input format is wrong. just post this:

```
"String content"
```

in your case i believe it would be like this:

```
"THIS IS A TEXT MESSAGE"
```